# Defining eventhandlers outside MainWindow?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to define some event handlers inside auser class but im not sure how. The MainWindow needs the handler definitions.

```
  public abstract partial class MainWindow: Window {
     public User user = new User();
  }

  public class User {
    internal void ExampleMouseEventDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      // Does stuff;
    }
  }
```

Isnt there a way to somehow make this work? Such as:

```
mainWindow.AddHandleDefinition += ExampleMouseEventDown();
```

Also tried this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        User user = new User(this);
    }
}

public class User
{
    internal User(MainWindow w)
    {
        w.AddObserverButton.MouseUp += ExampleMouseEventDown;
    }
    internal void ExampleMouseEventDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Does stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example should probably work, but what you're trying to do is not a good idea. Nobody but ManWindow should handle mouse events that happen in MainWindow. The reason for that is that everything turns into a giant tangled ball of yarn otherwise. If you want a mouse down in MainWindow to do something to some particular instance of `User`, the handler in MainWindow should call a method on that instance of `User`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you are right. Now that you mention it. Should I delete this question?